# How to find the xyz location of objects in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am still creating an adventure map for minecraft, but in order to do it I need to make a chest pop up with items in it. I have the code for that already, but I don't know where the chest is located in my world. I was wondering if anyone knew how to find an object's location in minecraft. I know how to find the player's location, but not a chest's. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Simple. stand were the chest is suppose to be press f3 and check the cords

Comment: so is the chest's coordinates the same as my player's coordinates? Just wasn't sure wether the chest's coordinates are specfic to a point on the chest or the whole chest in general. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have to make a new chest because in Vanilla Minecraft is no way to find a object. But there is a Chest Finder Mod but I think the last version was for Minecraft 1.5.2.